# Acceso a un array que está dentro de una clase C++

Tags: c++, c++11

No he encontrado modo de tener acceso al array que está dentro de mi clase heredada. ¿Me podrían ayudar a obtener acceso al array?¿Cómo podría hacerse?

```
class FacultadMecanica:public Universidad
{

    private:

    public:

        void CarrerasFacultadMecanica(){
            string *Carreras;
            Carreras=new string[2];
            Carreras[0]="Ing.Quimica";
            Carreras[1]="Ing.Mecanica";
            Carreras[2]="Ing.Electrica";
        }           

};
```

**Edit:**

Gracias por hacerme caer en cuenta los errores que cometi :)

Aqui dejo el codigo mas completo,desde main intento obtener los valores del array pero da error en las lineas indicadas.

```
    // Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Persona
{

private:


public:

void CarrerasArry(){string *Carreras;Carreras=new string[2];Carreras[0]="Ing.Quimica";Carreras[1]="Ing.Mecanica";} 

};

int main()
{

Persona Datos;

//En las dos lienas siguientes da erro :

cout<<Datos.Carreras[0]<<endl;

cout<<Carreras[0]<<endl;


}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo no puedes acceder?¿Qué error te da cuando intentas acceder?¿En qué línea del código compartido?

Comment: Me refiero a que ......por ejemplo quiero mostra el dato  Carreras[1] en el main...como lo haria ?

Answer (score 3):

Como norma general, en C++ hay dos formas posibles de que una función devuelva un resultado:

- Con un tipo de retorno.
- En un argumento por referencia o puntero.

Lo primero a comentar, antes de entrar en detalles sobre cómo devolver un dato, es que tienes un error garrafal en tu función:

```
void CarrerasFacultadMecanica(){
  string *Carreras;
  Carreras=new string[2];
  Carreras[0]="Ing.Quimica";
  Carreras[1]="Ing.Mecanica";
  Carreras[2]="Ing.Electrica"; // <<<--- AQUI!!!
}
```

Si `Carreras` lo preparas para admitir 2 objetos de tipo `string` no puedes pretender que en dicho arreglo entren tres elementos. Si tu creas un arreglo tal que `int* arreglo = new int[10]` has de ser consciente que `arreglo` únicamente va a admitir 10 enteros, accesibles éstos con los índices 0 a 9 y no 0-10). Este error provoca que pises memoria de tu propio programa, haciendo que éste se pueda comportar de forma errática.

Para evitar este tipo de problemas suele ser recomendable usar los contenedores de C++. En tu caso lo más lógico sería usar `std::vector`. Con esta solución ya no tendrías que preocuparte del tamaño del arreglo:

```
void CarrerasFacultadMecanica(){
  std::vector<string> Carreras;
  Carreras.push_back("Ing.Quimica");
  Carreras.push_back("Ing.Mecanica");
  Carreras.push_back("Ing.Electrica");
}
```

Volviendo a tu duda, para devolver un resultado generado dentro de una función hay, como norma general, dos posibles soluciones:

- Devolver el resultado usando el retorno de la función.
- Almacenar el resultado en un argumento, siendo éste un puntero o una referencia.

El caso más común es el primero y, aplicado a tu programa la solución podría quedar tal que:

```
string* CarrerasFacultadMecanica(){
  string *Carreras;
  Carreras=new string[3];
  Carreras[0]="Ing.Quimica";
  Carreras[1]="Ing.Mecanica";
  Carreras[2]="Ing.Electrica";

  return Carreras;
}
```

Como te he comentado, también podría almacenarse en un argumento, en este caso has de ser consciente que el argumento ha de ser una referencia o un puntero, es decir, ha de añadir un nivel de indirección a la variable. Dado que la variable a devolver es un arreglo, arreglo que inicializas con `new` todo sea dicho, necesitarías un puntero doble:

```
void CarrerasFacultadMecanica(string** Carreras){
  *Carreras=new string[3];
  *Carreras[0]="Ing.Quimica";
  *Carreras[1]="Ing.Mecanica";
  *Carreras[2]="Ing.Electrica";
}
```

Esta solución (aplicada así tal cual) plantea ciertas complicaciones. Habría que decidir, por ejemplo, qué hacer si a la función le llega un puntero que ya está inicializado. ¿Hay que borrarlo o basta con ignorar su estado anterior? Cada opción tiene implicaciones que habría que analizar en detalle.

Sin embargo, si hacemos caso a la recomendación que te he propuesto anteriormente y usamos contenedores de la stl la solución se torna más sencilla:

```
void CarrerasFacultadMecanica(std::vector<string>& Carreras){
  Carreras.clear(); // Borramos lo que haya en el vector
  Carreras.push_back("Ing.Quimica");
  Carreras.push_back("Ing.Mecanica");
  Carreras.push_back("Ing.Electrica");
}
```

Devolver un resultado a través de un argumento puede tener sentido en aquellas situaciones en las que una función ha de devolver varios tipos de resultados diferentes. Dado que mediante el `return` únicamente podemos devolver un tipo de resultado una posible solución es usar los argumentos para devolver el resto. Aunque insisto que es una *posible* solución.

Habría otras soluciones, como almacenar el resultado en la clase y ofrecerlo a través de un getter, pero a falta de más detalles no veo necesario desarrollar esa parte.